# Rails CSV import from scratch

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am rather new to using rails and website programming, apologizes for possible basic questions.

My website needs to upload a CSV file with the format:

```
Course_name #header
course1

Module_name #header
module1

Task_name,Task_description,Task_expected_result #header
mod1 task1 test,mod1 task2 test description,mod1 task1 test result
mod1 task2 test,mod1 task2 test description,mod1 task2 test result
mod1 task3 test,mod1 task3 test description,mod1 task3 test result

Module_name #header
module2

Task_name,Task_description,Task_expected_result
mod2 task1 test,mod2 task1 test description,mod2 task1 test result
mod2 task2 test,mod2 task2 test description,mod2 task2 test result
```

My database is set up that a course will have many modules, which in turn have many tasks.

Course > many modules > many tasks.

On my website I would like to upload the .csv file and then hit a button to upload the course.

I need the reading of the file, and thus the creation of the table entries to go as following:

1. read course_name until blank line is hit, create course using that name, grab the course_id of the newly created course.
2. read Module_name until blank line is hit, create the module using that name and the course_id(is how they are connected) and grab that module_id.
3. then read task_name, task_description and task_expected_results and create a task using all those values and the module_id, do this until a blank line is read.
4. then if not EOF and another module_name is read, repeat from module creation to task creation until EOF.

I know this is a lot to ask, I've tried searching online for help but i have not had any luck there. Any help with model/controller/view code would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: are you in control of the format of the file that is being sent in, or is it being generated elsewhere (outside of your control)? you would find it a lot easier if it can be passed to you as JSON, if that is a possibility

Comment: I am in control, its generated from the same page from an export course button. And its required to be in the format of CSV.

Comment: If the requirement is to be in this particular CSV format, then that is what it is.  a JSON export would be better, if you were able to work that way, but we can do CSV. Can you please include examples of the code that you've used so far, so that we can give specific advice?

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have much code, didnt get far with this one sadly.
in my views, i have(hopefully this formats properly in comments)

<%= form_with(multipart: true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :file, accept: ".csv" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Read CSV" %>
<% end %>
This, i believe, spawns the upload file thingy, with the submit button.

In my controller and model I dont have any code.

Comment: While it's hard to know exactly what you want to do with your system, hopefully the answer I've given will point you in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

You will need to modify this in order to get it to find/populate your objects, but this uses strings to get the data from the CSV.

First off I split your "CSV" based on there being a blank line gap between sections (as I said before, this is a lot like trying to send several dictionary/database files inside a CSV, rather than using a better computer interchange format)

using the sample of view that you added to the comment (as HAML):

```
= form_with(multipart: true) do |f|
  = f.file_field :file, accept: '.csv'
  = submit_tag 'Read CSV'
```

your file will now be passed into the Rails as an [ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.5/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile.html).

We can access the contents of this file, using the `#read' method:

```
mycsv = params[:file].read
```

my code for splitting, formatting, etc (assuming that the format of the file never changes):

```
require 'csv'

# first split the "string" into sections
csvarr = mycsv.split(/^$/).map(&:strip)

# the first section is going to be the course. so "shift" it out of the array,
# leaving us with an even number of remaining elements.
# since it's assumed that the first section will be the course, I don't bother
# checking that it is, and just store it's value
course_name = csvarr.shift.lines.last
# You probably want to do a "course = Course.find_or_create_by(name: course_name)"

# now loop through the remaining elements, 2 at a time
csvarr.each_slice(2) do |mod|

  # the first element in a block of 2 will be the header
  modname = mod[0].lines.last
  # You probably want to do a "module = Module.find_or_create_by(course: course, name: modname)"

  # the second element will be the associated data
  modcsv = CSV.parse(mod[1], headers: true)

  # loop through the data to show that we have it all correctly
  modcsv.each do |task|
    puts "Course: #{course_name} Module: #{modname} Task: #{task["Task_name"]}\n"
  end
end
```